# XSLT 2.0 - High Level Grouping with Sums (WordML)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, wordml

Dearest Professionals,

I have some joint billing XML code that has Time Card / Timekeeper summaries within.  I can easily group by a specific Matter, then by Timekeeper and get totals per matter. But I need to get a sum of all hours and billed amounts by timekeeper for the entire joint bill, not just per matter.

I have all code referenced below, but updated from @Tim-C 's comment. The XSL Transform link is [HERE](http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrzE/1)

**INPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<superbill>
    <invoice type="P" id="562845" number="562845">
        <matters>
            <matter number="014592-000007">
                <timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="NC1">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>NC1</initials>
                            <billingname>Nicholas J. Collins</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="BJB">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>BJB</initials>
                            <billingname>Billie J. Bob</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                </timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
            </matter>
            <matter number="014592-000091">
                <timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="NC1">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>NC1</initials>
                            <billingname>Nicholas J. Collins</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">1.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">525.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">1.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">525.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">1.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">525.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">1.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">525.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">1.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="BJB">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>BJB</initials>
                            <billingname>Billie J. Bob</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">11.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">6325.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">11.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">6325.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">11.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">6325.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">11.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">6325.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">11.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                </timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
            </matter>
            <matter number="014592-000092">
                <timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="NC1">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>NC1</initials>
                            <billingname>Nicholas J. Collins</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="BJB">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>BJB</initials>
                            <billingname>Billie J. Bob</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                </timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
            </matter> 
            <matter number="014592-000095">
                <timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="NC1">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>NC1</initials>
                            <billingname>Nicholas J. Collins</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2100.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2100.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2100.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2100.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="BJB">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>BJB</initials>
                            <billingname>Billie J. Bob</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">0.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                </timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
            </matter>
            <matter number="014592-000096">
                <timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="NC1">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>NC1</initials>
                            <billingname>Nicholas J. Collins</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">20.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">10500.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">20.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">10500.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">20.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">10500.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">525.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">20.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">10500.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">20.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                    <timekeeper-summary timekeeper-id="BJB">
                        <timekeeper>
                            <initials>BJB</initials>
                            <billingname>Billie J. Bob</billingname>
                        </timekeeper>
                        <timekeeper-summary-totals>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="billed">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2300.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="worked">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2300.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="standard">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2300.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate1">
                                <total type="rate">575.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">2300.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                            <timekeeper-summary-total type="timerate2">
                                <total type="rate">0.00</total>
                                <total type="hours">4.00</total>
                                <total type="amount">0.00</total>
                                <total type="adjustment">0.00</total>
                            </timekeeper-summary-total>
                        </timekeeper-summary-totals>
                    </timekeeper-summary>
                </timecard-summary-by-timekeeper>
            </matter>
        </matters>
    </invoice>
</superbill>
```

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
               xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="XJ_TKSummary_02" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="XJ_TKSummary_02">
       <xsl:variable name="TW" select="1440" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//superbill/invoice/matters/matter/timecard-summary-by-timekeeper/timekeeper-summary/timekeeper" group-by="../@timekeeper-id">
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t><xsl:value-of select="initials" /> - <xsl:value-of select="billingname" /></w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <xsl:variable name="groupTotals" select="current-group()/timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total" />
                    <w:t>
                        Hours: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($groupTotals[@type='hours']), '###,##0.00')" />
                        for $ <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($groupTotals[@type='amount']), '###,##0.00')" />
                    </w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

The desired totals should read...

```
NC1 - Nicholas J. Collins
Hours: 25.00 for $13,125.00

BJB - Billie J. Bob
Hours: 15.00 for $8,625.00
```

Any and all assistance would be appreciated.

Regard,

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is change the `xsl:for-each-group` to this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//invoice/matter/timecard-summary-by-timekeeper/timekeeper-summary/timekeeper" group-by="../@timekeeper-id">
```

So, you are grouping `timekeeper` records by their parent `timekeeper-id` attribute.

You also need to include the `timekeeper-summary-totals` in the xpath to get your total hours and amount.

```
<w:t>
  Hours: 
 <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total[@type='hours']), '###,##0.00')" />
 for $
 <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total[@type='amount']), '###,##0.00')" />
</w:t>
```

Or, better still, use a variable to cut down on the code repitition of the xpath

Try this abridged XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
               xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="XJ_TKSummary_02" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="XJ_TKSummary_02">
       <xsl:variable name="TW" select="1440" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//invoice/matter/timecard-summary-by-timekeeper/timekeeper-summary/timekeeper" group-by="../@timekeeper-id">
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t><xsl:value-of select="initials" /> - <xsl:value-of select="billingname" /></w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <xsl:variable name="groupTotals" select="current-group()/timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total" />
                    <w:t>
                        Hours: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($groupTotals[@type='hours']), '###,##0.00')" />
                        for $ <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($groupTotals[@type='amount']), '###,##0.00')" />
                    </w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm getting each individual timekeeper, but getting 0.00 for both the hours and the amount.

Comment: Just noticed that it's only taking the first matter into consideration. Just tested adding a 4th and 5th timekeeper into the 2nd matter in the XML, and it only lists out the 3 original timekeepers and not adding up the #'s. Something is keeping them at 0.00.

Comment: @NCollinsTE, consider to edit your question and provide a minimal byt complete input sample to demonstrate the problem. When I try to use your current snippet and Tim's code at http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwC is seems to output the values you have described so far.

Comment: @martin-honnen - I have created a snippet in the same manner with a full stripped down version of my XML file (removing all Client / Law Firm data from the file, changing attorney names and leaving time card information in tact). I'm still getting 0.00 hours and $0.00 for amount.  The first timekeeper should show 25 hours @ $13,125.00 and the second should show 15 hours @ $8,625.00

Comment: @NCollinsTE, you will need to edit your question and share the details to allow us to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: @martin-honnen Done.

Comment: In that sample the structure is a bit different so I think you want to change `<xsl:variable name="groupTotals" select="current-group()/timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total" />` to `<xsl:variable name="groupTotals" select="current-group()/../timekeeper-summary-totals/timekeeper-summary-total[@type='billed']/total" />`

Comment: As an alternative, you can adapt the grouping population as I have done in http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrzE/2 with e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="//superbill/invoice/matters/matter/timecard-summary-by-timekeeper/timekeeper-summary" group-by="@timekeeper-id">`